# Integrating facebook comments in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-comments

What's the best way to integrate facebook comments in iOS application?

I've placed a UIWebView with an iframe and managed to get the comments. The problem is it doesn't recognize the device login.

And for what I've searched, the Facebook SDK doesn't integrate the comments widget in iOS.

Is there a solution for it?